# SQL Server Database Mail: The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure

Tags: sql-server

I'm using `SQL Server 2012 Developer edition` to test Database Mail functionality. But I'm receiving the below error.

The steps I followed:

1. Installed e-mail certificate to Trusted root certification authorities.
2. Tested the e-mail functionality using `sa` user
3. Account 1 is using port 587 with SSL.

Account 2 is using port 465 with SSL.

Account 3 is using port 25 without SSL.

All accounts are with Basic authentication ( the user name and password is cross verified).

```
    The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. 
    
    (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2021-09-01T15:45:56). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.).
    
    Sending Mail using Account 2 (2021-09-01T15:47:36). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation has timed out.).
    
   Sending Mail using Account 3 (2021-09-01T15:47:57). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server xxx.xx.xx.xx (xxx.xx.xx.xx:25), connect error 10060).
```

Comment: Clearly 587 should work. What about using a proper certificate, which mail server are you using?

Comment: Our own mail server.

Comment: And does that not have a proper certificate (at least an in-house CA certificate)? That's not very good

Comment: @Charlieface There is any issue if we use the account `sa`. Should I use windows login ?

Comment: @Charlieface The certificate is already installed. How can I verify if the issue is with certificate ?

Comment: Doubt that makes a difference. Did you install the self-signed cert into User Certificates -> Trusted or Computer Certificates -> Trusted (should be the latter)? The issue is definitely with the certificate, that's what the error says

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236649/discussion-between-rauf-and-charlieface).

Comment: It can only ever work for ports 25 and 587, it won't work for port 465. SQL Server's Database Mail is implemented using an external .NET Framework-based application, DatabaseMail.exe, that uses an SmtpClient to connect and deliver mail. Due to limitations of [SmtpClient.EnableSsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl) this means that in Database Mail "SSL" actually means "STARTTLS support" so only works with mail servers on port 25 and port 587. Mail servers on port 465 use SMTP over TLS and SmtpClient cannot connect to those.

Comment: @Charlieface It worked when I copied to Computer Certificates. The set up is with 587 with SSL. Post as answer.